# Laravel 8 - Upload storage path changed, how to show old files?

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 8, I updated the storage path for image uploads. It was `app/violations/filename.jpeg`

```
if( $request->hasfile('violationStatement') )
        {
            $file = $request->file('violationStatement');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $violation->plateNumber . '-' . $violation->violationType . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('app/violations/', $filename);
            $violation->violationStatement = $filename;
        }
```

And it was updated to `app/violations/speeding/Toyota/XXX-1234/11-June-2022/11-26 AM/filename.jpeg`

```
if( $request->hasfile('violationStatement') )
        {
            $file = $request->file('violationStatement');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = 'violation-statement' . '-' . $violation->plateNumber . '-' . $violation->violationType . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('app/violations/' .
                $violation->violationType . '/' .
                $violation->carModel . '/' .
                $violation->plateNumber . '/' .
                Carbon::parse($violation->violationDateTime)->format('d-M-Y/H-i A'), $filename);
            $violation->violationStatement = $filename;
        }
```

The images are displayed in datatables, so obviously I'll have to change the image `src` to the new URL. When I do so, how can I also display the old images of the old directory?

Comment: As per my experience, there is no alternative way to do show old images. For showing it first you have to create a script which has ability to transfer all old images to new folder structure respectively and then it will work as before.

Comment: Create a route for the image-src in html and check in the controller function if the new path exists or the old one. https://image.intervention.io/v2 will help to serve the images.